# config dynamic route in nginx location directive

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

How can use regex for a variable segment for URL in nginx location directive exactly to match a dynamic URL like this /v2/user/1234 in this config:

```
location /v2/user/[id] {
proxy_pass http://new-service;
include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

I have searched but I found many complex and confusing guide.